# Angular2 large list scroll performance

Tags: performance, angular, infinite-scroll, immutable.js

I have an Angular4 app with an endless list, using `ngx-infinite-scroll:0.5.1`. I am also using lazy loading for each section of the website.

When I first enter the section with the large infinite-scroll-list, the performance is quite good, the scroll events are very responsive and everything feels quite smooth. I can then scroll to the end of the list (1000 component items), loading and attaching further chunks to the list, like so:

```
addToTileListData(tileDataList: any) {

   // Build temp list
   let tempTileDataList: List<PxTile> = List<PxTile>();

   for (let tileData of tileDataList.body) {

     const tile: PxTile = tileData as PxTile;
     tempTileDataList = tempTileDataList.set(tempTileDataList.size, tile);
   }

   // Merge temp list with visible data
   const newList = <List<PxTile>>this.tileList.concat(tempTileDataList);
   this.setTileList(newList);
}
```

The 1000 components are immutable.js items using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

When I leave the section and enter another lazy loading section, the previous section with the large list is destroyed.

But when I then navigate back again to the section with the large infinite list, the list quickly becomes very sluggish while scrolling, up to the point that, when I scroll to the end of the list of 1000 items, the scrolling almost freezes.

Do you have any suggestions what the problem could be? Or how I should proceed? Does this problem sound like a memory leak?

If I check the performance tab of the Chrome developer tool I can see that at the same time, dozends of scoll events stack on top of eachother:

[image]

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: You could try detaching the change detector for components that you know aren't changing. Inject ChangeDetectorRef and call detach. You can re-attach it if you know it needs to be updated.

Comment: I've detached the ChangeDetectorRef and the list seems to behave smoother at the first lazy load of that module, but when I switch to other lazy loaded modules (and the list get's destroyed in the meantime), and then change back to the lazy loaded module with the list (which is loaded anew), the list will then still behave very sluggish, the more I scroll down and the more new data is being loaded and attached to the bottom of the list. Any other idea what I could do?

Comment: Try enabling production mode. Maybe Angular's extra debug checks are slowing it down.

Comment: It really did help. Thanks a bunch! I've also added .first() in front of my api call - that also contributed to making it faster :)